# Element Fails to Assign to Variable

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'm trying to change the innerHTML attribute of the elements with ids `containDiv` and `status`, however it only changes `containDiv` not `status`. When I look in the console it says "Cannot set property `innerHTML` of undefined" so it would seem it can't find the element, but I have no idea why. If anyone could help me out with this, that'd be great.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/css_all.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="header">Current Status:</div>
            <div style="padding:2px 0px 0px 2px;">
                <div id="containDiv" class="i18n-replaced">
                    <span id="status" class="block_count_number"></span>
                    loading...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/wtf.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkStatus(){
    var hostname = window.location.hostname,
        status = document.getElementById("status"),
        container = document.getElementById("containDiv");

    if(hostname==="stackoverflow.com" || hostname==="facebook.com" || hostname==="youtube.com"){
        status.innerHTML = "Active ";
        container.innerHTML = "on this page.";
    }
    else {
        status.innerHTML = "Not Active ";
        container.innerHTML = "on this page.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`status` is inside `containDiv`... Once you overwrite new HTML in `containDiv`, `status` does not exist anymore.

Comment: -_- Stupid mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Derek said, try:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="header">Current Status:</div>
        <div style="padding:2px 0px 0px 2px;">
            <div id="containDiv" class="i18n-replaced">loading...</div>
            <span id="status" class="block_count_number"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Or something similar for what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I just reformatted it, so it's essentially this. Thanks anyway.